# Umbraco change page template dynamically

Tags: templates, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.5.8.  I would like for a page to switch to another template if the browser being used is certain versions of internet explorer.  I wasn't sure how to do this or if it could be done.

Comment: You should probably use JavaScript to detect the browser and redirect to the right template. You can load the same page with different templates just appending the template name to the page url like '/my-alt-template'.

Comment: Is it possible to change the template for a page in code?

Comment: Yes, you can create you own controllers: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding the `altTemplate` parameter to the URL, e.g:

```
my-domain.com/my-page?altTemplate=newTemplateName
```

works right out of the box (just make sure to add the new template to the document type's "Allowed Templates" in Umbraco). Combined with Mario's suggestion to use JavaScript, this should do it.